# I'm having trouble with the sql language functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working in the SQL language for **1 month**. That's why I may not understand things. But I always get an error when creating these functions. I wrote the codes down there. The error message is as follows:

> **Only one expression can be specified in the select list when**
>   **the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.**

```
CREATE FUNCTION deneme(
    @ID int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value nvarchar(max)
    SET @value = (
        SELECT * FROM information
        WHERE @ID = Person_id
    )
    RETURN @value
END
```

Comment: What is the confusion?  `information` would seem to have more than one column, so you cannot assign it to a single variable.

Comment: And you have @value defined as nvarchar(max) but you return an int.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What do I have to do if I want to return it as a line.

Comment: table valued function then

Comment: This sounds a lot like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: I agree with Sean on this one but this is an example to create a TVF http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-valued-functions/

Comment: @Codeblogger If you wish to return the 'line' aka 'Row' or 'Record' as you would call it you would first need to Define your Record Type and then STORE the record into that Type.  With your code you have defined an `nvarchar`.  You can concatenate your fields and then store them into your @value variable like this... `SELECT field1 + ' ' + field2 + ' ' + field3  FROM information
        WHERE @ID = Person_id`.  There is also a `CONCAT()` function you can use in SQL Server.

Comment: Why don't you just use function creation templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign all columns values into one variable like that, and since you're passing an `ID` of the person and you want your function to returns the info of that person

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.deneme
(
  @ID int
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(300)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(300) = N'';

  SELECT @Value = CONCAT(I.FirstName, N' ', I.LastName)
  FROM Information I
  WHERE I.PersonId = @ID;

  RETURN @Value;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out you are trying to place multiple columns/fields in a single column/field.

@ID is a single column.  "Select *" is presumably returning more than a single column or else it wouldn't be much help!

In order to change this and make it work as you are trying here, you would need to concat the columns you are trying to return.  This is almost surely not the best way to accomplish this but sometimes concating names (for example) is fine.

The other issue you may be running into is even if you changed this to "Select ID" but still have errors it may be because the query returns more than one row matching that criteria.  You can work around this (it is a work around most of the time) by limiting the number of rows returned with "TOP 1".  But be careful as this may not return the information you want.  You can use an order by statement to help ensure it is the correct information (such as order by Time_entered).

The code below with "TOP 1" and concatenating multiple columns (and casting as the same type) will always work.

Again, these are not Best Practices and shouldn't be used to sanitize data in production... but it does show you why you are getting these errors and how to prevent them.

```
CREATE FUNCTION deneme(
    @ID int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @value nvarchar(max)
    SET @value = (
        SELECT TOP 1 cast(First_name as nvarchar) + N' ' + cast(Last_name as nvarchar) FROM information
        WHERE @ID = Person_id
        Order by Time_entered desc
    )
    RETURN @value
END
```

Comment: You have some bad coding habits here. First is using top 1 but no ORDER BY. Without an order by you can't ensure which row will be returned. Then you are casting to a nvarchar but you don't specify the length. This means it will use the default? https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: Dude, we're trying to explain why you can't put multiple columns into a single column through a function.  Putting an order by clause in there isn't going to help when it's supposed to be looking for a single value, presumably the primary key, in the where clause... I don't expect him to copy/paste this code into your payroll software.

Comment: Then why introduce TOP 1 in the first place? Notice I didn't downvote or anything. You did roll up some code and post it as an example. It is obvious the OP is pretty new. Therefore when you post code it shouldn't be sloppy. Not saying it has to be perfect but it shouldn't have obvious issues like that. In a real situation I would suggest either a computed column or an inline table valued function instead of a scalar function.

Comment: Because I just know his next issue is going to be related to too many rows returned.  I specifically addressed this in the answer.  I will update to include info about TOP.